# jQuery DataTables Ordering By 2 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to style and give functionality to one of my tables:

[image]

**My Goal**

Order by whether or not the type of funding is active or not.. which is what it is doing currently as you can see.  Now, I would like to order the `Funding` column alphabetically.. so my wanted outcome should be:

```
Funding One
Funding Two
Funding Three
Funding Four
Alpha
Beta
Charlie
Test
test2
```

Here is what I have so far my datatables script:

```
var codeFundingTable = $("#Code-Funding-Table").DataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [2] },
        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [2] }
    ],
    "columns": [
        { "orderData": [1] },
        { "orderData": [0] }
    ]
});
```

So I am first ordering by column 1 (`Active`, 0-based) then by column 0 (`Funding`) but it is not doing it alphabetically.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: What happens if you switch the orderData 1 and 0? Does it order by Funding only?

Comment: @Bango correct, it orders alphabetically without any regard for being active or not

Comment: can you create a fiddle with sample data..? Here is a starting point -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/948/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a guess since we have no sample data. For example, what is the value of "active" (besides a checkbox is rendered)? But I believe you can just do

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  order: [[1, 'asc'], [0, 'asc']]
})
```

- active column is sorted first, if values is 0 and 1 asc should be used
- first column is secondly sorted alpha, with respect of second column order

---

Here is a demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/949/** `position` is sorted first, then `name` is sorted within each `position` "type".

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size

```
"columns": [
    { "orderData": [1,0] },
```

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help.  It would be the same as `{ "orderData": [0] },
                    { "orderData": [1] }`

Comment: It 'would be' the same, if you did try it; or you did try it, and it is the same? Also note that your Active column contains HTML which oftentimes interferes with functionality like searching and sorting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what helped me is this.
I used data-order attribute to sort my tables.

```
data-order="[[ 0, &quot;asc&quot; ], [ 1, &quot;asc&quot; ]]
```